# Struggling to get Grafana Faro shipping Web metrics to Prometheus

Tags: grafana, grafana-faro

I'm investigating whether I can use [Grafana Faro](https://grafana.com/oss/faro/) in combination with existing use of Prometheus to instrument some static web sites. I've been using Google Analytics but looking to migrate.

IIUC I should be able to include `<script>` tags on static pages to import the Faro Web SDK and emit basic metrics including [Web Vitals](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/frontend-observability/faro-web-sdk/components/provided-instrumentations/#web-vitals).

The Prometheus server **is** receiving (624) Grafana Agent, Grafana Faro [App Agent Receiver](https://grafana.com/docs/agent/latest/static/configuration/integrations/integrations-next/app-agent-receiver-config/) and Blackbox Exporter metrics from the Grafana Agent.

```
count by(__name) ({__name__=~".+",agent_hostname="{my-host}:12345"})
624
```

But I'm unable to discern from Grafana's docs and from interrogating the Prometheus server, metrics that appear to correspond to the Web metrics. Am I correct to assume that I'll receive metrics from Web Vitals from Faro sent by the Agent to Prometheus?

My JavaScript isn't great but I'm confident I'm importing the libraries correctly (the Faro documentation makes no reference to importing Web Vitals but I assume that must be done).

I expect to be able to "find" metrics that correspond either to the Web Vitals or to the explicit `cart-transaction` metric in the JavsScript (though I believe these may route to Loki and then need on-sending from there)

I would appreciate any "Doh!" explanations for any of the above.

Grafana Agent config (`agent.yaml`):

```
server:
  log_level: info
metrics:
  wal_directory: /tmp/wal
  global:
    scrape_interval: 1m
  configs:
    - name: default
      remote_write:
      - url: http://localhost:9090/api/v1/write
integrations:
  agent: {}
  cadvisor: {}
  metrics:
    autoscrape:
      enable: true
      metrics_instance: default
  app_agent_receiver_configs:
  -  autoscrape:
       enable: true
       metrics_instance: default
     instance: frontend
     server:
       host: 0.0.0.0
       port: 8888
       api_key: secret
       cors_allowed_origins:
       - "http://localhost:8080"
  blackbox:
    blackbox_targets:
    - name: Ackal
      address: https://google.com
      module: http_2xx
    blackbox_config:
      modules:
        http_2xx:
          prober: http
          timeout: 5s
          http:
            method: GET
```

I have a single HTML page client referencing this JavaScript

```
import {
    onCLS,
    onFID,
    onLCP,
} from "https://esm.run/web-vitals";

onCLS(console.log);
onFID(console.log);
onLCP(console.log);

import {
    createSession,
    initializeFaro,
} from "https://esm.run/@grafana/faro-web-sdk";

const faro = initializeFaro({
    url: "http://localhost:8888/collect",
    apiKey: "secret",  
    app: {
        name: 'frontend',
        version: '1.0.0',
    },
});

// log with context
faro.api.pushLog(['Sending update'], {
  context: {
    payload: "payload",
  },
  level: LogLevel.TRACE,
});

// set user metadata, to be included with every event. All properties optional
faro.api.setUser({
  email: 'bob@example.com',
  id: '123abc',
  username: 'bob',
  attributes: {
    role: 'manager',
  },
});

// unset user
faro.api.resetUser();

// set session metadata, to be included with every event
faro.api.setSession(createSession({ plan: 'paid' }));

// unset session
faro.api.resetSession();

// push measurement
faro.api.pushMeasurement({
  type: 'cart-transaction',
  values: {
    delay: 122,
    duration: 4000,
  },
});
```